# Functions.php ou functions.fcn

Tags: php

Aprendi a incluir um arquivo <kbd>.fcn</kbd>

Gostaria de saber se há diferença entre incluir um arquivo functions.php e um functions.fcn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para o PHP não há diferença, você pode incluir um arquivo <kbd>.php</kbd>, <kbd>.html</kbd>, <kbd>.phtml</kbd>, <kbd>.fcn</kbd>, <kbd>.class</kbd>, <kbd>.tpl</kbd>, <kbd>.qualquercoisa</kbd>. **O que importa é se é um arquivo de texto**.

Se dentro desse arquivo de texto tiver as **tags do PHP `<?php`, `<?`, `<?=?>`, `<% %>` `<%= %>`** ele vai *parsear* normalmente.

<sub>**Atenção:** Algumas tags já não são suportadas na versão 7, como as tags do *ASP* (`<% %>`, `<%=`)
As *tags* curtas `<?` e `<?=` depende da configuração  `short_open_tag` do <kbd>php.ini</kbd>.

[Referência: Manual PHP<sup>EN</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)</sub>